# html helper @enumdropdownlistfor is not sending the value to the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, ado.net, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

`enumdropdownlist` is used only with strings not integers.

i want to show admin management in `dropdown` in view.

if user select admin background value of admin which is 1 send to the model
if user select management background value of manage which is 2 send to the model.

`enumdropdownlist` is coming with string not integers.

I want model which is come with integers 
hope anyone understand.

see this is my model

```
public class tbl_Login
{
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public roles userrole { get; set; }
}
public enum roles
{
    Management,
    Admin
}
```

this is is my view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(Model => Model.userrole,"Select",new { @class = 
"form-control" })
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn- 
flat" />
</div>
}
```

instead of asp.net code

```
<select class="form-control">
<option>--Select--</option>
<option>Admin</option>
<option>Management</option>
</select>
```

finally this is my controller.

```
// I want this controller with log come with value i.e admin=1 or management=2.
public ActionResult Login(tbl_Login log)
{
    string uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    if (log.userrole == 'Admin')
    {
            ...
    }
    return View();
}
```

I want to compare this in controller

```
if(log.userrole==1)
{
}
```

Comment: Edit format and Words

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

In your controller you can do this:

```
if ((int)role == 1)
{
   // your logic here ...
}
```

**Some information about Enums and how you can handle them:**

Cast an integer value to a Enum like this:

```
roles role = (roles)yourIntValue;
```

Or like this

```
roles role= (roles)Enum.ToObject(typeof(roles) , yourIntValue);
```

From a string you could do something along these lines:

```
roles role= (roles) Enum.Parse(typeof(roles), yourStringValue);
```

Comment: @Abdulmubeen, have you been able to use my provided solution? Is something still unclear?